# Chat client with GWT

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, gwt, gwt-rpc

What would be the best way to create a JS chat client with GWT? The bit that I'm having trouble with is the persistence and transfer of the messages. Should I store the messages in a DB and check the db for new messages? Is there a much better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like jah suggested, you definitely want to use Comet/Server Push/Reverse AJAX/many other names. I've compiled your options for GWT in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391203/what-does-it-call-in-gwt-to-make-2-ui-consistent/2394227#2394227).

If you want a quick start, look at the [NGiNX_HTTP_Push_Module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/) - they have an easy to understand chat example. You'll have to write some handling of the protocol yourself, but it's a rather simple task.

If you're using Java too on the backend, the easier solution will be [rocket-gwt](http://code.google.com/p/rocket-gwt/) or [cometd](http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/).

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into this - Server Push/whatever looks perfect for what I'm trying to accomplish.

One more thing though, if you're still here: How should I store the messages on the server between them being sent and received?

Comment: Like jah suggested - use a simple class, probably only with getters and setters, for that. You might also want to look into JavaScript Overlay Objects for much easier handling of JSON responses from the server: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay.html

Comment: Btw, do you know if this will work on Google App Engine? Thank you!

Comment: If you are using Google App Engine then my guess is rocket-gwt is the way to go - APE and nginx push module both require specialized servers, which AFAIK are not available on GAE. On the other hand, rocket-gwt should integrate pretty nicely - but I don't have much experience with GAE myself, so it's just a guess :)

Answer (score 2):

You could either have connected clients continuously poll the server for new messages or you could have a look at Server Push:
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/ServerPushFAQ

Comment: No, there wouldn't be any need - unless you want to keep some kind of chat history on the server.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused (new to GWT, too). Should I just use a standard data structure then to store the messages?

Comment: Yes.  Have a look at the NewMessageEvent class from a GWT chat application:
http://code.google.com/p/gwt-eclipsecon-chat/source/browse/trunk/src/org/eclipsecon/gwt/chattr/client/