# best way to update client site data in GWT application

Tags: java, gwt

When getting data from the server to the client side in GWT application we need to refresh every period of time to get updates for data, I think this is not a good method because if consume lot of time and resources, just thinking about another method is amazing :), any one get a good and effeciant idea ??

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2391203/what-does-it-call-in-gwt-to-make-2-ui-consistent/

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at server push technologies, like [Comet for GWT](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet-streamhub/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should definitely have a look at JBoss Errai (http://www.jboss.org/errai) - very cool and promising thing. Will be even shown off at Google IO this year.